# REGEX: get specific number in url

Tags: php, regex

i try to get product id from this url, the pattern is try to find number after `p-` and before `.html`

```
http://www.domain.com/jp-37025-shoes-red-p-362060.html?stores=203
http://www.domain.com/pp-66743-shoes-red-p-665322.html?stores=12
```

result should be:

```
362060
665322
```

my current code:

```
$subject = "http://www.domain.com/jp-37025-shoes-red-p-362060.html?stores=203";
$patern = '/\W*[a-z]\D*/';
$string = preg_replace($patern, '', $subject);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use parenthesis to match exacly like this:

```
preg_match("/p-(\d+)\.html/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

For example the first string matches like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => p-362060.html
    [1] => 362060
)
```

Comment: it's ok i found the pattern something like this `/_*[0-9]*(?:_(\d+))/`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is preg_match, not preg_replace.

```
preg_match ( '/(\d+)\.html/', $subject, $matches );

echo $matches [1];
```